# cannot get a numerical value from the excel cell

Tags: java, excel, selenium, testing

```
public Object[][] dataProviderMethod() throws IOException {

    try {
        file = new FileInputStream(new File("/Users/nanthakumar/Documents/workspace/Myna_Admin/src/com/myna/testdata/login.xls"));
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        row = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
        col = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
        data = new String[row][col];

        for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            rowvalue = sheet.getRow(i);
            for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                cellValue = rowvalue.getCell(j);
                data[i][j] = cellValue.getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println("The value is ----->" + data[i][j]);
            }

            workbook.close();
            file.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException nana) {
        nana.printStackTrace();
    }



    return data;
}
```

This is my code and I tried to add the `getnumericalCellvalue()` instead of `getStringCellValue()` but that is not working for me.

Comment: Could you explain your error better?, Do you have maybe a stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you have to check in the template excel whether the column is number or text.you can get the numerical value if and only if the column is of type number.so change the template excel and try

Comment: i checked it.still the result is same.

Comment: what is the exception you are getting?

Comment: i got this error::java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell

Comment: that's what I mentioned above .Your column type is text not numeric.Either you can change the type of your column in excel template and use the same code, or you just change the code to getStringCellValue instead of getNumericalCellValue